# Update angular meta tags/data twice on single component on click event

Tags: angular, typescript, metadata, meta-tags

I have a scenario where product listing and product detail view are on the same component. On page load I show product listing and on product click I hide product listing and show product detail view using *ngIf.

Now I want to set Meta tag for both the view.

On page load I am setting Meta tags for the product listing with generic details:

```
ngOnInit(): void {

        if(!this.route.snapshot.queryParams['productId']){
            this.utils.updateMetaTags('Harvesting farmer network - buy direct from farmer', 'Helping farmers in India sell their crops!', this.route.url, 'assets/images/logo.svg');
        }
 }
```

Now, once user click on product from product listing, I want to update Meta data with product details.

```
getFeedById(){

this.utils.updateMetaTags(this.title, this.singleItemFeed?.description || 'Helping farmers in India sell their crops!', this.router.url, this.singleItemFeed.images[0]?.url);

}
```

Result: I am able to set initial Generic Meta but meta are not updating for the products.

**Important Points:**
Angular Version: 11.0.2,
Angular Universal Implemented

**Is it possible to update Meta data more than once for a component on events like click without reloading the page?**

Answer (score 1):

You may use subscribe query params change:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params.productId);
})
```

Because when the query params change, the component will not reload. If using `this.route.snapshot.queryParams['productId']`, it will fire only once time when component init

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am already doing that. getFeedById() function gets product details which we use for Meta data update. And getFeedById() gets call by subscribing to queryParams. Implementation is not an issue. But, Is it possible to update Meta data more than once for a component on events like click without reloading the page?

Comment: maybe I don't understand your problem very well, can you provide more information through images or source code about your problem?